# My magento contact us form works in chrome, but does not let you type in other browser

Tags: forms, google-chrome, magento, contacts

I ran into this very strange issue a few hours ago. I have this Magento Site: http://www.naturalvitaminc.com/index.php/contacts and the contact form on that page just doesn't seem to be working properly. On Google Chrome it functions perfectly letting you enter information as needed and submitting it correctly. But when you go to it on any other browser you cannot type anything into any of the fields, except for the comments field. So I was hoping someone can take a look at it and let me know what could be happening and any possible fixes for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can type in any browser, but the text is hidden because of CSS styles. I'm no expert in CSS, but I see that in your case `box-sizing: border-box` works in Chrome and other browsers in different ways. Because of that the input fields are so small, that you can't see any text that is entered in them.

I think you should get rid of box-sizing. Go to **local.css, line 346**. And change it from

```
.col2-set .col-1 .form-list input.input-text, .col2-set .col-1 .form-list textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 13px 4px;
}
```

to

```
.col2-set .col-1 .form-list input.input-text, .col2-set .col-1 .form-list textarea {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

Also you will probably have to change width of these fields.